# How to use HSQLdb with Ibatis

Tags: java, unit-testing, hsqldb, ibatis, in-memory-database

I want to use in memory database to query for data in my unit testing, my project is Ibatis (with annotation) for querying actual database which I want to mimic with the help of HSQLDB.

Please help me with how to configure iBatis with HSQLDB.

Also is there any way to these better for unit testing with code which is strongly dependent on database in its functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can make an iBatis sqlMappings.xml config file something like this:

```
<sql-map-config>

  <properties resource="configuration.properties" />

  <!--The datasource for you application is configured here: -->
  <datasource name = "hsql"
      factory-class="com.ibatis.db.sqlmap.datasource.SimpleDataSourceFactory" 
      default="true">
    <property name="JDBC.Driver" value=""/>
    <property name="JDBC.ConnectionURL" value=""/>
    <property name="JDBC.Username" value=""/>
    <property name="JDBC.Password" value=""/> 
  </datasource>

  <!--Declare the SQL Maps to be loaded for this application. 
      Be sure it's in your classpath. -->
  <sql-map resource="maps/beanMappings.xml"/>


</sql-map-config>
```

plus a congifuration.properties file like this:

```
JDBC.Driver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
JDBC.ConnectionURL=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/myDb
JDBC.Username=sa
JDBC.Password=
```

and then use it like this:

```
String resource = "maps/SqlMapConfig.xml";
Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader(resource);
SqlMap sqlMap = XmlSqlMapBuilder.buildSqlMap(reader);
```

Comment: my project doesnt use xml for config it uses a prop file where i can give dbname, user, pass n host